# C# Return new string vs .ToString()

Tags: c#, arrays, string, new-operator, tostring

Take the following code:

```
public static string ReverseIt(string myString)
{
    char[] foo = myString.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(foo);
    return new string(foo);
}
```

I understand that strings are immutable, but what I don't understand is why a new string needs to be called?

```
return new string(foo);
```

Instead of

```
return foo.ToString();
```

I have to assume it has something to do with reassembling the CharArray (but that's just a guess).

What's the difference between the two and how do you know when to return a new string as opposed to returning a System.String that represents the current object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simply, because calling ToString() on a char array gives you

> System.Char[]

Try

```
    char[] ca = "Hello world".ToCharArray();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ca);
```

You don't get `Hello World`

**Also** calling Array.Reverse to reverse strings is a bad idea, [Tony and Jon mention it in their - now famous - Stack Overflow Presentation](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/jon-skeet-at-stack-overflow-dev-days-london)

Answer (score 2):

The second just calls ToString on an instance of char array, while the first uses a string constructor to obtain a string from a char array. They really have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the IL for the 2 functions:

```
private string test(String myString){

        char[] foo = myString.ToCharArray(); 
        Array.Reverse(foo); 
        return new string(foo); 
}


test:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  callvirt    System.String.ToCharArray
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     
IL_0009:  call        System.Array.Reverse
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     
IL_0010:  newobj      System.String..ctor
IL_0015:  stloc.1     
IL_0016:  br.s        IL_0018
IL_0018:  ldloc.1     
IL_0019:  ret         


private string tess(String myString)
{

        char[] foo = myString.ToCharArray(); 
        Array.Reverse(foo); 
        return foo.ToString(); 
}

tess:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.1     
IL_0002:  callvirt    System.String.ToCharArray
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     
IL_0009:  call        System.Array.Reverse
IL_000E:  nop         
IL_000F:  ldloc.0     
IL_0010:  callvirt    System.Object.ToString
IL_0015:  stloc.1     
IL_0016:  br.s        IL_0018
IL_0018:  ldloc.1     
IL_0019:  ret
```

Answer (score -1):

An array of characters has a speedier/optimized external call to the CLR in the string constructor, so in this case, it's a faster operation.

`String` has a specific constructor for this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern String(char[] value);
```

Comment: I'd guess that the call to .ToString() is actually faster, but that is unimportant given that it doesn't do the same thing as the string constructor.